# Does the Low State in NE555 go to GND?

Tags: 555, hardware

Here is the first schematic that I created : [image: Circuit for 6s High state and 3s Low State using NE555 IC].

The Vcc is at 5.1V and I a self made using the LM317, Works Fine.

When I checked the Output with the [Multi-meter I use.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DT9205A-AC-DC-LCD-Display-Professional-Electric-Handheld-Tester-Meter-Digital-Multimeter-Multimetro-Ammeter-Multitester/32678598851.html), I was getting a high state of around 3.9V(Which I guess was fair enough.), but the Low was was giving an out of 2.5 ~ 2.6V, which to me seems a concern because the NE555 datasheet shows low state going to 0V in one of the [image: graphs that shows the waveform in the astable operation.].

I even tried simulating the circuit afterwards and this is what it looks like in simulation and even in the hardware set up : 
[image: Same values].

And what am I supposed to make out of this?
[image: Voltage Low Level]

So now I am getting a High state of 3.6V(seems fine), but the low state is still around 2.6V.

How do I find out the root of the Issue and how should I debug it?

[image: Schematic of the 5V Power Supply being used.]

Comment: 1) Does the LED turn off? If Yes, then why is it a problem? 2) Temporarily short the LED and measure again, if then the voltage still does not go down to 0 V then the NE555 might be broken.

Comment: 1)It dims down, not off. 2)Didn't get it, Do you mean connecting anode and cathode both on Pin 3(Output) of 555?

Comment: 2) yes connecting anode and cathode both on Pin 3 But the fact that the LED only dims (does not turn off) means that your circuit is not the same as your schematic or the NE555 is broken. I am 100% sure that the LED should go **off** when the ouput is low with the circuit as drawn above. **Maybe** there is some ripple on the supply so try connecting a 10 uF capacitor between the supply rails.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie bad IC it was!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that particular circuit yes the output should go close to ground.

If it is not, either

1. the 555 is sick or
2. you MUST be pulling current from somewhere else... or
3. perhaps the oscillator is still oscillating at some higher frequency, or,
4. Your 5V supply is not flat DC.

Using a scope would help a lot.

You could try lifting the output pin and see if it still does it and measure what the voltage is at the top of the LED to eliminate item 2.

Comment: It is one breadboard, pulled the output pin out. 1)Voltage measured directly on Pin is 3.7 and 2.6. 2)No Voltage on LED

Comment: @MaNyYaCk yes pull the output pin. ALso are you sure your 5V is actually 5V DC with low ripple.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk what does your 5V rail measure on AC and DC.

Comment: On DC : 5.13, On AC : 0.03. I added the schematic of the power supply as well.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk WHat does the output pin measure on AC?

Comment: Constantly fluctuating anywhere between -0.91 to 1.23.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71476/discussion-between-manyyack-and-trevor-g).